# Extremely slow move generation in chess engine

Tags: engines

I am making my first chess engine in python (which is obviously not that fast). I am using the mailbox approach rather than bitboards, as switching would likely take more effort than just restarting the project. I use pseudo legal move generation, and currently my program can generate about 150k nodes per second (I can get 80 million nps on stockfish perft). Any tips other than switching to bitboards?

Comment: Err...don't use Python?